# How to delete all event listeners at once in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, listeners

I'm making a small game in as3.

The game contains 10 levels.

When i enter 1 level everything is alright. But when i enter the second level (frame) the event listeners from the first frame are still working and a recieve a warning saying ' Cannot access an object of null objct reference'. This is because i delete every object of the first level and th add the objects from stage 2.

I've tried using removeEventListeners, but it doesn't work, cause ENTER_FRAME Listeners work one more time after I remove the Event Listeners.

I've tried using different frames for different levels, bit it doesn't work. Also i tried using 1 frmae for all 10 frames, but i recieve much many warning and the Flash Loader is overloaded.

How can i switch through levels (back and forward)? Thanks in advance.

```
  addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, subtracting2);
     arrListeners.pop(); // poping it out of the array because it will be deleted after the count reaches 0
     function subtracting2 (e:Event):void
     {
        count--;
        var FAcoef:Number = count/30; //
        FadeAway.alpha = FAcoef; //                   Some effect like FadeAway
        setChildIndex(FadeAway, numChildren - 1); //
        if(count == 0)
       {
            setChildIndex(FadeAway, 0);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, subtracting2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't. If you don't want to bother you with events (**asynchronous**), try [AS3 Signals](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals) (**synchronous**).

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't add event listeners in an enterframe loop...

Comment: I have to add ENTER_FRAME to check if the level is passed and to be sure that the game laws are no broken. 

It doesn't have to be my idea whick is right (with remove EventListeners). As long as it works fine, I will accept any idea

Comment: What conditions will pass someone to the next level?

Comment: The game is a puzzle game where you need to have certain amount of points to pass the level

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built-in way to remove all listeners.

You could use weak references to let the listeners be removed when the object is Garbage Collected.

object.addEventListener( ......, ......., false, 0, true );

Or you could add the removeAllListeners functionality yourself, [here is some info](https://web.archive.org/web/20110810191228/http://blog.reyco1.com/method-of-removing-all-event-listeners/) (Have a look at Ion comment)

But.. you shouldn't need any of the above if you take care to remove every event listener straight away when it is not needed any more.

If you have a class with one or more event listeners which are needed till the end of the instance's life, you should create a destroy() function. In that destroy() function you would remove all the event listeners.

In your case, you could call destroy() before you go to second level(frame).

Comment: If I try using weak reference and Garbage Collected, how can i remove Event Listeners that are connected to the stage?

And if i delete the object, should I call it again to start the event listener again?

Comment: what do you mean by "deleting the object" ? nulling it or removing from stage?

Comment: How can i use destroy()? As much as I know destroy is not method or function in AS3

Comment: Man i tried the code from the link that you give. Changed addEventListener method works fine and catches every listener and put it in an array, but when i use clearEvents() it doesn't work.

I think that EvewntListeners that are previously removed are the problem, because they are still in the list. How can i delete the, because i don't kno their index number in the array?

Comment: how are you adding the event listeners? Can you show this bit of code?

Comment: See the post I edited it. There is a little bit of code. But i think i worked it out.

Comment: Also it has a problem with assigning events to children. So should i add obj:Object to the parametars in addEventListener override function?

(type:String, listener:Function, obj:Object useCapture:Boolean=false, priority:int=0, useWeakReference:Boolean=false):void