# Action Script 3, How to disable keys?

Tags: actionscript-3

If there's too many functions, so It is very hard to "removeEventListener" each one,
Is there any way to disable all keys temporarily?

Thank you.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144812/how-to-delete-all-event-listeners-at-once-in-as3

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is there any way to disable all keys temporarily?"*

Can you not just use `.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN...`?

Either your `Stage` or some `MovieClip` is listening for key press event, right? eg:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handle_KeyPress);
```

Where your `handle_KeyPress` function, which **handles all key presses**, looks like:

```
function handle_KeyPress ( evt:KeyboardEvent ) : void
{ 
    //# RIGHT ARROW or numpad 6 (arrow)
    if ( evt.keyCode == 39 || evt.keyCode == 54 || evt.keyCode == 102) 
    { 
        //do something if Right arrow
    } 

    //# SPACE BAR
    if ( evt.keyCode == 32)
    { 
        //do something if Space bar
    } 

}
```

**PS:** 
Show an example of code with *"too many functions"* (eg: give small example how they're spread out it). It's possible you need to re-think / re-structure your code if it's not currently flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to temporarily "pause" the event handlers, you could throw in a simple boolean:

```
var eventsHandled:Boolean = true;
```

And inside the event handler functions you would use it as a condition:

```
function buttonClicked(evt:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(eventsHandled){
      //do stuff
```

This is just a simple bandage. VC.One's answer is probably hinting into your actual problem and in some point you'll have to face it.